# How can I highlight possible duplicates of a question if it has not been closed (yet)?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I came across the following question: [Graphical/Browser-Based PHP Unit Testing Suite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235644/graphical-browser-based-php-unit-testing-suite)

The question is definitely a duplicate, as stated in its comment, but I overlooked that link when first seeing the question, and jumped right to the answers. The accepted answer wasn't much help to me, but I found an okay solution through another answer, but only after some more searching.

That being what happened, I would've had to spent much less time searching if I had actually noticed the "duplicate" link in the comment. And this leads me to my question: **How would one highlight another (possibly duplicate) question, that has much higher quality information on the topic than the current one, especially on questions that have been inactive for some time?**

My first idea was to add something like the following to the original question:

---

### [Example] Additional information can be found [here](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl).

---

But then I wondered if it was okay to modify a question like that (which is why I am asking here now).

- While I understand that I *could* add an answer, answers containing only a link are very often downvoted on Stack Overflow (often justifiably so), and downvoted answers are not likely to receive much attention.
- I could also create another comment, but comments are very often entirely overlooked, as was the case with the comment that was already there.
- Another solution to highlight a question as a duplicate is to close it as a duplicate (duh), but that takes a bunch of people voting to close it (which I did), and that rarely happens on old question (at least that is my impression).
- One could think of a mechanism that displays "possible duplicate" close suggestions more prominently than in a comment, like so:

[image]

Doing nothing and telling me to look at the comments next time would be fine too I guess (I'll probably do that in the future anyway), but as I think that it should be as easy as possible to find high quality information on Stack Overflow, I figured that we as a community could come up with a better solution than that.

Comment: Why not vote up the comment informing you of the duplicate?

Comment: Oh yeah, I indeed forgot to do that. Nonetheless, I think a comment, even an upvoted one, if too easily overlooked.

Comment: @x3ro I think if someone overlooks the standard duplicate comment, they likely won't see anything like what you suggest. Also, a good number of possible dupes turn out not to be dupes (the dupe voter mistook something in the post), and this would be distracting, I think.

Comment: What you say is contradictory, imho. Either it isn't more likely to be seen than a comment, in which case it isn't any more distracting than a comment would be, _or_ it is more likely to be seen than a comment, in which case it might be more distracting if the duplication votes are wrong.

Comment: Also, I can only speak for myself, but I'd be way more likely to see something like what I've suggested compared to a comment.

Comment: How about if we highlighted the comment so it stands out against the background a little bit?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to go to Chat and ask other users to help in closing. Users holding a gold badge in one of the tags can close questions as a duplicate [on their own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/295232) now (as can ♦ moderators); otherwise, you need a few more users.

Some sites have dedicated chatrooms for this:

- [Stack Overflow Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) (please check their [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq#how-and-why-do-i-need-to-format-my-cv-pls-and-other-requests) first)
- Mathematics has the [CRUDE (Close/Reopen/Undelete/Delete/Edit)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/crude) room
- On Ask Ubuntu, there's [Raiders of the Lost Downboat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3877/raiders-of-the-lost-downboat)

Otherwise, you can use the hamburger menu on the right to navigate to the chatrooms associated with the site:

[image]

check for a room dedicated to moderation, the topic of the question, or else try the 'main' chatroom (if there is any).