# Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, tag-badges, dupehammer

In order to increase the efficiency with which poor quality questions are closed, it could make sense to have weighted close votes for a small subset of qualified users.

A very good way to measure the qualified users would be to leverage the tag badges. However, it needs to be rationally limited to a set of users that are knowledgeable with the subject. A very good way to measure the top users in a tag would be to look at those who have a gold badge in the tag.

If two users who have a gold tag badge pertinent to a question issue a close vote, the question should probably be closed (or probably will be very soon under the current system). I think **it would make sense to allow users with a gold tag badge to have a 3x weight for close votes in those tags**.

Please keep in mind, this isn't suggesting full moderator one click closure. It only adds weight to the vote. A single user could not do it on their own. These singular users cast close votes all the time, so that aspect would not change. Some will vote to close, some wont, but the ones who do should have a stronger weight to their vote. Even with 3x it will require 2 of said votes to accomplish, or still 2 other users (meaning 3 agreed it should be closed - which is the same amount of high rep users it takes to delete a question and that has a much greater impact than closure).

tldr;

Allow gold tag badge users to have a weighted close vote in their tag

Comment: It makes sense probably only for SO, not network-wide.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure this isn't *more* useful network-wide, @Łukasz웃Lツ... On SO, it would be a great help in improving moderation - on many SE sites, it would offer an incentive to the community to start encouraging consistent tagging.

Comment: Would they also have greater weight for reopening?

Comment: @Troyen - That is an interesting point, I am not sure that is as much of a problem. That would probably be a separate issue.

Comment: How are tag edits going to be handled? Before the question is closed, if a close vote is made that counts for 3x but then the tag that made the vote 3x is edited out, is the vote still counting as 3x? What if it is the other way around, and adding a tag would make a vote that was 1x, count for 3x? After the question is closed, do tags edits cause a recomputation that could reopen the question? I'd suggest that the answer should be "no". But before closure, it's not as clear to me how edits should be handled.

Comment: I may be biased, but this would be a problem on Programming Puzzles and Code Golf, where over half the posts are tagged [code-golf]...

Comment: IMHO, this only makes sense to apply to the initial tags on a post, @Louis - anything else is ripe for abuse and/or a headache to actually calculate. The "what if" numbers in my answer all reflect this assumption.

Comment: Is this really a problem right now? How many questions are hanging around that should be closed, but aren't? Hopefully that can be answered with some form of evidence rather than anecdotally.

Comment: @Yuck http://stackoverflow.com/review and to a lesser extent, http://superuser.com/review and http://askubuntu.com/review

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ I'd even suggest this on Super User

Answer (score 271, accepted):

**Update:** this is now enabled everywhere!

The rules are:

- You can instantly close *as a duplicate* any question that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.
- You can instantly reopen any question *closed as a duplicate* that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.
- You can only close or reopen a given question *once* (this hasn't changed).
- If you get in a fight with someone over whether a question should be closed, moderators will be notified and they'll <s>hit everyone with hammers</s> lock everything down and tell you to go home.

Remember: duplicates are questions that *ask for a solution to fundamentally identical problems* - many questions have similar or identical *answers* but are not duplicates. By the same token, many questions are asked using *very* different wordings but seek to solve identical questions - closing these helps folks find their way to a solution even when they don't know what terms to search for.

Enjoy your mighty hammer responsibly!

---

We're doing this for duplicates only to start, because it's incredibly silly *not* to do this. *Not* giving people with gold tag badges more abilities in their tags is just wasting some very valuable signal - here's why:

- If you have a gold badge in your tag, you *know* what's been asked before, in several iterations, and where to find it.
- If you have a gold badge in your tag, you *usually* have a great deal of knowledge about the topic and can consider technical accuracy along with perceived quality.<sup>1</sup>

Therefore, we're going to be rolling out a change that gives you more power when it comes to handling duplicates, a chronic source of pain. If a question has a tag where you have a gold badge, and it was part of the *original* set of tags applied to the question, you can mark it as a duplicate with a single vote.

Likewise, if you have a gold tag badge in one of the original tags of something marked as a duplicate and feel a mistake was made, you can re-open it with a single vote and (optionally) mark it as a duplicate of another (theoretically better) question.

Same rules apply, you get only one close / re-open vote per question. Additionally, if a question goes through two iterations of being opened and closed where this new 'Thor's Hammer' was used, moderators will get a flag alerting them to a contested duplicate.

This is being deployed initially as an experiment, I think there's enough sanity here to prevent most abuse cases, and we *don't* really have a very large rate of incorrect duplicates. If this pans out well, we might consider giving gold tag badge holders more weight in other areas, and possibly considering silver tag badge holders.

Smaller sites aren't going to care about this, and that's as it should be - they generally don't have the problem of being overrun with duplicates. I like this because it's a feature that becomes available *as you begin seeing the problem it's designed to solve*.

Jarrod is working on it now.

***Update***

To show my commitment to this, here's **my** version of the now famous PHP '[hammer](https://www.flickr.com/photos/raindrift/sets/72157629492908038)':

[image: php-duplicate-hammer]

<sup>1</sup><sub>There are those that get them by providing a lot of crappy answers to duplicate questions. Closing these faster will become a sort of self-fulfilling fix for that.</sub>

Comment: As an aside, a lot of work is going into the whole duplicate process, but that's a topic for a separate post.

Comment: This is good stuff. I propose duplicates _all the time_, and I get frustrated when the question gets only two more dupe votes and three answers, all of which repeat information from the original. It will also make me more cautious about my proposals; but I like that too, because the Hammer means I can take my time finding the right link and still be effective. (That said, I'm still thinking that gold badge = 3 close votes would be best from a "checks and balances" point of view. But we'll see how it plays out.)

Comment: +1 for closing a dupe *before* a dozen half-assed answers can snatch the low hanging fruit

Comment: @JoshCaswell People _naturally_ want to answer, heck - often with just a link to the duplicate. We're actually going to _embrace_ that a tiny bit by making it incredibly easy to _not_ half-ass it by loading in pre-quoted / pre-attributed copy of the top voted answer, and letting you add a bit of context around it to make it better suit the OP's needs. Additionally, we're looking at ways for folks to convert up-votes _on_ those answers to close votes on the question, without deducting from your daily close vote limit. All whiteboard now, but will have more details next week.

Comment: This is great Tim! I assume that if a tag is later added to the question, and it's the only one where you have a gold badge, the binding vote does not exist? I ask because quite often questions get tagged as sql-server or mysql when they meant the opposite.

Comment: The [original PHP hammer](http://blog.codinghorror.com/content/images/uploads/2012/06/6a0120a85dcdae970b017742d249d5970d-800wi.jpg) needz moar Thor.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It has to be part of the original set - because that's the _only_ way to prevent someone from just adding a tag so they can close a question. I know that's going to be a problem, but the potential to abuse this privilege would be so amazingly high if I didn't have that guard in place that I doubt it would reach implementation. Can _look_ at refining it later, let's see what folks do with this for a little while, then talk possible tweaks.

Comment: This is amazing. There's celebration in the [PHP room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) and you're invited, @TimPost.

Comment: @RobertHarvey http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16369657#16369657

Comment: @TimPost thanks Tim, largely I'm fine with it, just seeking clarification in my words. :-)

Comment: Should "original" include tags that were added by the *author* after the question was initially created? For example maybe I forgot to add a tag.

Comment: Holy crap I just closed a question all by myself! I feel simultaneously dirty and almighty. Like if Superman took out the trash or something.

Comment: I would only suggest that if things _do_ seem to work out badly, consider dialing back only partially, like 2 votes from gold badge owners or something. Also, I haven't used it yet, but from others I seem to gather that there's no UI warning that your vote will be binding. Is that the case?

Comment: Please make this a feature that individual sites can turn on or off. Music.SE, which I'm somewhat active in,  is [suffering from too many closed questions](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/738/music-se-suffers-from-trigger-happy-closers), and I suspect having this feature wouldn't help the situation.

Comment: @Kevin If it becomes a problem, we can look at turning it off on certain sites. I'd _really_ like to see the _if_ in this, though. This is one of those features that 'appears' for a site as it _probably_ needs to have it. We're going to be watching this very carefully.

Comment: @Tim admit it, you posted this just to get tons of precious MSE rep! :-D

Comment: @TimPost seriously now, I think we should have some indication that a power user with gold badge cast a binding vote otherwise Meta will be flooded with questions. I have a mockup in mind, want me to post it as answer?

Comment: @ShadowWizard In the works - probably just a gold badge circle next to their name. Let's give this 24 or so more hours to be sure we're not backing it out entirely, and we'll see about it.

Comment: Yeah, [that's what I have in mind too](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eL37a.png), linking to this post and with some meaningul tooltip. :)

Comment: It'll have a meaningful tool tip, something like "Earned a gold badge in an applied tag, unlocks additional duplicate management privileges" - if we keep it then it will be just part of 'how do duplicates work'.

Comment: Mmmm... thanks but at least on SO the problematic questions that we're spammed with are _so localised_ that it is incredibly difficult to find dupe targets for them. As such this won't really make a dent.

Comment: @Kevin - as discussed on meta.music, we don't have any gold tag folks on Music.SE = no problem. And although I am likely to be the first one, I am a mod already, so... business as usual :-)

Comment: I suspect "if a question goes through two iterations of being opened and closed" should be one and a half iterations (close, open, close) instead. But I guess time will tell.

Comment: Re "it was part of the *original* set of tags applied to the question": I suspect that the same people who don't check for duplicates before asking likely don't tag appropriately.

Comment: "...many questions are asked using very different wordings but seek to solve identical questions - closing these helps folks find their way to a solution even when they don't know what terms to search for." I do not agree with this. I had a question a few weeks ago for I could not find a single piece of information on because the ways I did word it returned nothing useful. When I did get an answer I was looking for, I searched using keywords from that answer and found heaps of information, so much so that I never really had to ask the question in the first place, had I known those keywords.

Comment: @gamewin1 If we closed that question as a duplicate, people who searched using terms like yours would also find their way to the keyword-laden answers. Duplicates are signposts, not roadblocks.

Comment: @gamewin1 a closed post is not the same as a deleted one. Anybody searching using the same terms you used will find your duplicate, which leads them via a single click to the uber question. This helps keep the answers consolidated in one place, hopefully including the *best* answer.

Comment: I don't want to be a superhero. I believe that this represents an abandonment of the democratic principals that made StackOverflow so attractive in the first place. When I cast a close vote, I was happy that my vote was (effectively) reviewed by a set of my peers. Now this is gone, it makes me appear totalitarian and this perception of me has a negative impact on the friendliness of the site. I'd like to be part of a 5-person panel, not judge, jury and executioner... Is it silly that in the UK we have a right to trial by jury, despite the judges all holding their respective legal gold-badges?

Comment: ...and yes, I'm usually very confident of my close votes... but that's not my point.

Comment: @user133351 That's why this applies to _duplicates_ only, and there's more improvements on the burner to help make it a better overall experience. Gold tag badge holders _know_ when something has been asked before, at least generally. While it does give certain people more ability, it's _not_ less oversight - incorrect dupes (which are not very common) can be re-opened by another gold tag badge user, moderator, or 5 people in the community. We won't be extending this to any other close type.

Comment: @user133351 Also, the _quality_ of the site was a chief ingredient when it came to attracting people - we can't lose sight of that, and duplicates (especially constant, low-quality duplicates) are a _major_ concern when it comes to that.

Comment: Will this be extended to giving sliver tag badge holders slightly more power - maybe 2 votes out of five?

Comment: One point of clarification please: if I understand, one can earn a gold badge for a "famous question" (maybe I have that wrong)... but that doesn't sound like the kind of tag-knowledgeability you're talking about (many famous question badge holders have low rep in that tag). Are gold badges for famous questions also included in this feature?

Comment: This is now 2 months old - do you have any update on how successful it's been and whether it's going to stay (you tagged the question review 'cause you were going to review it). Thanks!

Comment: I would agree that *(a)* this is great; *(b)* I don't always want this. Even though I have a lot of knowledge about a tag, sometimes I'm still not sure whether a question is really a dupe. Can we have **both options** (a **Close** button + a **Vote to Close** button)?

Comment: @zx81 The whole thing is about gold **tag** badges, those with the name of a tag on them (like php or jQuery). "Famous Question" etc are not  tag badges.

Comment: @jtbandes That has been requested and [declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231507/).

Comment: this is not working anymore http://stackoverflow.com/q/25050636/1771795

Comment: @Omar - The jquery-mobile tag was not part of the original set (it was edited in), and therefore was not part of the duperhammer power.

Comment: Can this be extended to the tag family for programming langauge tags? For example I have a the gold badge in C++ but the hammer does not apply for C++11, C++14 etc... For the C tag this similar tags would probably be C99, C11 etc... Is there an argument to be made against this?

Comment: Tim, they seem to [complain over there at MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289101/839601) that dupehammer closures cast an old-fashioned banner "exact duplicate" instead of typical "has an answer here”. Could you please take a look?

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate. See [this meta question and answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289610/212464)

Comment: @TimPost The review queue seem to keep growing (apart from the reviews simply ignored). I've swung my opinion, I think gold badge users should have more powers. At the cryptography site hardly any question gets put on hold; that's not good. On the other hand: there are only 3 gold badge users and only 1 active (hi). But the language tags should be able to help there. So ... any update on this? Dupes seems to work fine.

Comment: @TimPost It's been about 4 years since this was implemented. You mentioned the *possibility* of extending this to silver badge holders. Has there ever been any progress on making this a reality? Alternatively (For silver badges), how about instead of making it a full swing of a hammer (5 votes), make it 3 or 4 votes, so it at least requires one other to agree?

Comment: @TimPost, I argue the same as Maarten & Franker, my post on Meta [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364755/answering-questions-when-no-attempt-has-been-made). Please consider, for example, allowing 2 Gold badge holders to close broad / unclear questions.

Comment: [Hammer time!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otCpCn0l4Wo)

Comment: @Tim Is it possible to change the language in the bullet points (particularly the "originally asked with a tag") to take into account the behaviour documented [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268278)? It's confusingly different to the final behaviour of the system (any question with the tag, so long as you didn't edit it in). This seems to be the canonical resource for this mechanism, and it'd be good to have it correspond exactly with the system behaviour. And it'd also be good to have it as faq, while we're here.

Comment: Possibly the symmetry about reopening should be removed. You know, the cucumbers can easily earn dupe hammer privileges. And are not shy about using it to protect their rep gains.

Comment: Shouldn't Thor be using runes, though? ᛈᚺᛈ

Answer (score 98):

I have a few thoughts on this...

First, if we're gonna do this then let's make it worthwhile: **1 vote == closed**, regardless of how many other votes or flags are in play. My biggest beef with close *voting* is [the execution-squad attitude](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41062/add-a-way-for-moderators-to-cast-a-normal-non-binding-vote/41333#41333) it seems to inspire among folks: "oh, I don't want to take responsibility for closing a question, I just want to be one of the mob throwing stones". If we're gonna give more weight to votes from folks who according to their past participation we *should* be able to trust with them, I want them to be taking that extra responsibility seriously.

Second, this power should be based on the tags in the *first* revision of the question. I know, that cuts out a lot of potentially-useful effects when it comes to niche tags - but it also cuts out a ton of potential for abuse, without also making it a major headache to figure out what a given vote is actually worth. For the tags where this actually *matters*, it matters because they happen to also be the most obvious tags for a whole bunch of questions - *if* you want an answer, that is.

Third, this has to apply to re-open votes as well. Philosophically, it's just *the right thing to do* - but it also makes sense from a practical perspective, since you can't [*undo*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) a binding vote if you make a mistake or the asker fixes their post.

Fourth, normal limits apply: you get a finite number of votes, and you can't vote twice, even if the post gets re-opened, even if *you* re-open the post. **No gold member close-wars!**

Lastly, there are *not that many* folks with gold badges floating around right now. Here's the breakdown by site:

```
Gold-tag-badge-having
Users   Site
1845    Stack Overflow
34  Mathematics
17  TeX - LaTeX
10  Server Fault
8   Super User
8   Database Administrators
5   English Language and Usage
5   Code Review
5   MathOverflow
4   Role-playing Games
3   Unix and Linux
3   Drupal Answers
3   Jewish Life and Learning
2   Gaming
2   GIS
2   Apple
2   Personal Finance and Money
2   Science Fiction
2   Mathematica
1   Home Improvement
1   Game Developers
1   Webmasters
1   Physics
1   IT Security
1   Graphic Design
1   Code Golf
1   User Experience
1   English Language Learners
```

Yes, that means the gold tag badge users on Stack Overflow could, in theory, close 92 *thousand* questions every day just by using all their votes. That's 10 times the number of questions SO actually *gets* every day. Think about that a little bit.

So... *What if* we had silently implemented this on Stack Overflow a year ago, and no one had altered their behavior...

- **22,102** questions currently open with pending close votes would instead be closed.
- **145,843** questions currently closed would have been closed *faster* and with less effort needed from other voters. 90,722 of these would have been closed with a single vote.
- **34,837** questions currently open would have been closed instead of the vote aging away. Note that 11,677 of these went through review and were marked "Leave Open".
- **2,677** questions would have been closed faster, but then reopened anyway.
- **1,328** questions would have been *reopened* faster
- **1,837** questions would have been reopened instead of the vote aging away. Note that 1,829 of these went through review and were marked "Leave Closed".
- **1,071** questions would have been re-opened faster, but then closed again.

Note that during the past year on Stack Overflow, 362,220 questions were closed and 8,108 questions were reopened.

Comment: So, conclusions... that doing so generates a small amount of noise, but it's still worth it? I'm not entirely sure what your stance on this is, but that's, at least, how I read this.

Comment: I'm still *thinking* about it. This would be a huge, huge change - I'm not averse to it, but I've no desire to support it without thinking through the implications first. This is just my initial thoughts... and some data I happen to have access to that most of you don't.

Comment: +1 Just for *considering* this idea along with all the risks. Though it has me wondering how much it would get abused for a gold member to cast a binding reopen vote just to post an answer.

Comment: Well, it would clearly have a much larger *proportional* effect on reopening than it would on closing, @Mysticial - even assuming folks wouldn't significantly alter their behavior. Which, of course, they would.

Comment: If it is only based on the tags in the first revision, people can escape from this by simply mis-tagging them, which is something [new users typically do](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23354842/revisions). If it is based on the last revision, it will be open to a lot of abuse. I don't really think changing the closing mechanism based on tags is a good solution.

Comment: Keep in mind, @Antony, that this "escape" just puts them in the same situation they would be in *now*.

Comment: A big issue is how we would deal with users that misuse this power, suspension is a bit too big of a hammer here, but I also don't think we need yet another manual ban from some part of the site like the review bans. The system should make sure that those actions get enough review, and that any contradictory information generated from review creates a flag. If a user is overridden in their close/open decisions too often, they would lose the binding vote (temporarily?). I think this really needs another safeguard except the domain knowledge one.

Comment: I am intrigued by this idea, but I don't think the mistagging loophole can be sewn up: the same people who post questions that need to be closed also don't  generally bother using tags correctly. Perhaps this should only apply to duplicate closures? (That could also be used just as a toe in the water to see how it works out.)

Comment: Let's assume: a) most gold tag badge users to be [Types 1 or 3](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077). b) 3s don't close much because answers are rep. c) 3s won't abuse answer-then-close (for very long). d) 1s already consider themselves caretakers, so they'd try to avoid abuse. Do we have many gold tag badge users that aren't 1/3s? I'm not sure we really need to wring hands over abuse possibilities. However, knowing my closevote would be immediate and binding, I would likely use it *way less* than I am now because I'd need to be absolutely sure that the question is really closeable.

Comment: @Shog9, would it be possible to re-run those numbers with gold tag badge users having the power of *three* closevotes instead of a binding vote?  With three votes, there'd still need to be *at least* one other gold tag badge user or two normal users agreeing with the close.  This reduces some of the hypothetical abuse, leaves room for error, and leaves room for consensus.

Comment: @MadScientist: abuse of this power could be dealt with by revoking the relevant gold badges. That would have the side-effect that the binding-vote power on those tags would also be revoked without affecting other rights.

Comment: @MadScientist: I'd say abuse of this right is *well* worthy of suspension, as these users are likely to have been on this site for long and should know what's acceptable and what's not. That's some large power that they have by being able to single-handedly close or reopen questions, and there needs to be severe consequences for misuing that power.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I'm more thinking about not outright intentional misuse, but essentially just bad judgement. Any behaviour that becomes sufficiently disruptive is worthy of suspension, but suspensions should not be the primary defense against misuse of this ability.

Comment: @MadScientist: yes, I'd agree that there are different degrees of misuse. However, I'd say that asking the user directly or bringing up the user's actions on Meta would be sufficient if it's just a matter of disagreement -- I don't think there's any need to implement any sort of special ban for this.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I don't agree with revoking gold badges. ***Those are well-earned from writing good answers.***

Comment: @Cupcake In theory, yes.  In practice, meh.  People can earn quite a lot of rep from posting a lot of mediocre content.  SO is certainly way more about quantity than quality when it comes to rewarding contributions.

Comment: I like this in principle (my somewhat [related request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105755) also focused on badge based privileges). The problem here is that the fate of a Q is highly dependent on what tags you choose. In some ways it already is: n00b Qs in C++ and PHP are more likely to get murdered than in R or haskell, but giving the posse these tools might exacerbate the problem. Not only that, the limitation to the tags in the first revision also suggests a possible workaround: Tag it with low traffic/soft tags and then revise with the correct tags (or wait for someone else to do it)

Comment: `"1,837 questions would have been reopened instead of the vote aging away. Note that 1,829 of these went through review and were marked "Leave Closed"."` - so (1) the reviewers are messing up big time, (2) the difference in opinions regarding what should and shouldn't be closed is disturbing, (3) binding reopen votes would be a bad idea, or (4) I'm reading the stats wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure about the first revision tags thing either - people use the weirdest tags on their questions sometimes (obliviously, I assume). I'm more for punishing abuse.

Comment: Agreed on not liking the first rev tags thing; seems like it's actually opening up an avenue to abuse, frankly. Help vampires will just learn to tag their questions wrong (i.e. using tags with no gold badges given), and when they do this, it generates more work fixing tags for the rest of us, and also becomes the one place where the rest of us, as a community, *cannot fix the problem*.

Comment: I am very unhappy with the performance of the reopen queue, @Dukeling - this is a pretty good example of how it consistently overrides the opinions of *subject matter experts*. There are ways to improve that a little bit, but I haven't had the time to actually put them into action.

Comment: For folks worried about the "first revision" restriction destroying the utility of this (@Dukeling, Billy): even taking into account tags in *all* revisions, we're talking at best a 2-3% increase in closed questions over the past year. It may turn out that it's overly-paranoid, but it won't make much of a difference in any case.

Comment: 1 vote == closed? That seems extreme. Can't it be triple vote weight or something instead?

Comment: @bjb568 **having your question closed is not The End of the World.** Anyone can edit their question and/or take the issue to Meta Stack Overflow. **Closed questions can be re-opened, but only if they're fit to be not-Closed.** I am frequently disappointed by how ***infrequently*** people bother to edit their closed question to improve it and have it be re-opened `:P`

Comment: @Cupcake I `love` your *use* of **formatting**. Anyway, closing and reopening seems like unnecessary work - we should optimize for least amount of average review-work (and time) to get to the "correct" state. I don't know exactly what's the best, I'm just concerned that a bunch of reopening after just *one* closevote might be counterproductive.

Comment: @bjb568 that's a fair argument. `*** +1 *** !!! :D <3 <3 <3`

Comment: people don't abuse their rep based powers....

Comment: @Shog9 I just encountered a case where the OP added the golden tag in a [second edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27224584/revisions#rev-arrow-8f70f048-6c12-4cb8-bbb6-8a8b7ddd7585). Because of this, the dupehammer did not work. Because it is the OP themself who added the tag in a revision, the arguments about abuse prevention do not apply. Is this a known bug, and if so, will it be fixed?

Answer (score 28):

I think this ends up placing a slightly arcane restriction on how sites can use tags, and gives an inordinate amount of influence to a small group of users who may not necessarily be reliably trusted with moderation.

**It changes the balance of a site significantly by linking two previously entirely unlinked systems.**

Consider Meta for a moment. (I know it's not completely analogous, but bear with me.) I'm pretty dern close to a gold discussion badge. I know a *lot* of other people have them as well. The problem is, the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag is one of several tags which are most frequently used on Meta.

Consider, for a moment, a site in which there are a few tags which are *very* frequently used. Users who attain a gold badge in those tags would, logically, be able to cast heavy weight on a significant portion of questions. That gives these users an inordinate amount of power in this circumstance. In this way, it limits what sites can and can't do with tags. It creates a multidimensional matrix of power balance - **a question for each site becomes, "how can we balance tag usage with the power we give users?"**

This, I think, is a problematic question. You've taken two systems which are normally entirely dissociated from each other and linked the balance of power directly to them. While this isn't normally a huge issue, it has potentially unforeseeable consequences on a site for which tag usage differs, by consensus, from what we would expect in other sites.

**This should be enabled on a per-site basis.**

I don't think this would be an issue if it were enabled on a per-site and by-need basis. However, we need to take a good look at the users this affects. Thinking about this applied to all sites, I believe you'll quickly agree that there really aren't many users on most sites that would gain any privileges from this. With the exception of Stack Overflow:

- This means that, for a community to vote to enable this feature, they'd effectively be voting on the people, not the idea.
- This privilege carries a significant amount of power.

  - This means that a *very* small number of users (for most sites, one or two)  gain an inordinate amount of influence over other users' posts.
  - Since most sites have a far lower question volume, there would be effectively no restriction on the number of weighted votes one could cast in one's tag area. This is a problem pretty much everywhere except Stack Overflow, and maybe Mathematics/TeX/Trilogy.
- High tag score does not necessarily correlate with high trust, in the same way that we have high-rep and low-rep moderators.

---

tl;dr?

This proposal links two previously completely unlinked systems. It gives a *very* small number of unelected users (with the exception of Stack Overflow) a *lot* of power over questions in their tag category. High tag score does not necessarily correlate with trust, which means that small handful of unelected users have the capacity to do undue harm to the community.

While this is a good idea, on most sites, it upsets the careful balance of power that is community consensus. This is a significant problem.

If you wanted to enable it on Stack Overflow, though, it might be a good idea to post it on Meta Stack Overflow - the community there will better be able to decide.

Comment: This would be exceptionally weird on meta sites, since those have 4 *mandatory* tags, one of which *must* apply to every question before it can be posted.

Comment: @Shog9 That's why I used it as an extreme example of a restriction on tag usage - most sites wouldn't be able to use tags in the way Meta does (even to a far lesser extent), where all questions of a category X are tagged. It would give those users a huge amount of power on the site.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/727/discussion-between-travis-j-and-emracool)

Comment: "High tag score does not necessarily correlate with trust" except it does. High tag score correlates to high rep score (for a gold badge most likely you're over 10 or 20k) which correlates to trust: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: @hayd But... really? In all cases? You can't imagine someone getting a gold badge who really shouldn't have this moderation privilege?

Comment: @Emracool I can (and there are such people), but historically the SE system has always given out trust with reputation. My point is these people are *already* trusted with the means to do "undue harm" e.g. via editing without consensus. I'd advocate assuming each person is "good" until they demonstrate otherwise.

Comment: @hayd That's true. The risk is that close votes aren't necessarily seen if executed unilaterally in the background. Edits are.

Comment: @Shog9, I don't know how this *was* implemented, but it seems like the obvious solution to this objection would be: If a site has *mandatory* tags (which AFAIK is just Meta), gold tag badge holders for those mandatory tags don't get dupe hammers.

Comment: A more realistic example would be the `embedded` tag on SO. What sense does it make for an ARM expert to be able to single-handedly close/reopen AtMega questions?

Answer (score 20):

I was curious as to how many gold badges there were in various tags on Stack Overflow (the site with the most gold badge holders according to another answer), so I (semi-manually) scraped https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold and sorted it by decreasing number of gold badges (excluding tags with fewer than 5 gold badges):

```
             c#  293
           java  254
            c++  216
     javascript  183
         python  176
            php  139
         jquery  136
              c   91
        android   85
            sql   73
    objective-c   71
           .net   71
         iphone   69
              r   54
           html   50
            ios   49
            css   40
          mysql   38
           perl   37
           ruby   34
     sql-server   33
        asp.net   31
          regex   29
          scala   25
        haskell   24
         delphi   24
           bash   21
  ruby-on-rails   20
           linq   17
         oracle   16
            wpf   15
           tsql   15
          swing   15
          c++11   15
            git   14
         django   13
         vb.net   12
         string   11
     powershell   11
          linux   11
         spring   10
 multithreading   10
            vim    9
sql-server-2008    9
         matlab    9
            xml    8
          shell    8
       winforms    7
     postgresql    7
             f#    7
          cocoa    7
    asp.net-mvc    7
            wcf    6
      templates    6
sql-server-2005    6
        node.js    6
        mongodb    6
           list    6
         arrays    6
           xslt    5
        windows    5
ruby-on-rails-3    5
            jpa    5
      hibernate    5
       generics    5
        eclipse    5
     batch-file    5
            awk    5
      algorithm    5
           ajax    5
```

Additionally, there are 13 tags with only 4 gold badges, 24 tags with only 3 gold badges, 48 tags with only 2 gold badges, and 174 tags with only a single member with a gold badge in that tag. There are roughly 38988 tags (1083 pages with 9 rows and 4 columns of tags on each page, according to https://stackoverflow.com/tags).

In the high volume tags, there are many gold badge holders, so there should be balance. In the low volume tags, there are not, but they are no worse off under this proposal than they are now. They area of most concern is the tags where there are few gold badge holders and those members may hold undue sway. I'm assuming that any abuse will be flagged and dealt with appropriately; I don't know if this increased vote weight (or closing privileges in general) can be suspended/revoked from an account, but that would seem appropriate if there is abuse of this.

Answer (score 17):

After a long time study of how StackOverflow in general behaves on this subject, I think we should actually extend the possibilities for closing questions as off topic for gold and possibly silver badge holders.

I do have currently a gold badge for cryptography & encryption but I can see this has limited effect on the site as most of the questions that should be closed *are not duplicates*. **Currently hardly any cryptography related questions get closed at all**.

I'll leave this answer as it invites informed discussion and a counter argument to above view.

**Votes for this answer should still be for the old answer displayed below, which I do not support anymore**.

---

The problem is that most gold badges are for popular tags, mostly languages and runtimes on SO. And the gold badge holders are not automatically experts on all the different techniques. This will lead to false-positives, that are difficult to reverse.

As an example: lets check my stats: I'm at over 600 for [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption) right now and over 400 for [cryptography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cryptography). Nice, but after a lot of questions, not even near a gold badge.

Now almost all of the crypto questions are also tagged with a specific runtime; if they aren't they are mostly off-topic. However, not everybody with a gold badge for - for instance - Java knows much about crypto. So you get an "expert" with a gold badge closing a question that can be answered (or, reopening one that cannot be answered). And the actual expert is helpless; the amount of traffic we get for crypto questions is currently already too low to close questions, let alone reopen them.

Now I've just taken my field of expertise as an example; I do think there are many many of these "niche" tags and fields, and I assume (hopefully correctly) that most of the gold badges are for really popular tags. All in all, an interesting idea, but I don't think that this will work as intended.

Comment: _This won't work_ -- somehow, this statement doesn't match the data I see. "**145,843** questions currently closed would have been closed faster and with less effort needed from other voters. **90,722** of these would have been closed with a single vote" ([see stats in this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230882/165773)).

Comment: @gnat Yeah, but for my specific field, lots of questions would be closed that should not be closed, and because of the low amount of traffic, they would all have to be reopened with help of a moderator. And the moderator is not very likely to know anything about crypto either. I'm not afraid that too few questions get closed, with this proposal you will only see more questions closed (it is a question of false-positives and negatives).

Comment: I see, your concern makes sense indeed. Consider [edit]ing the answer to better present it - at the first reading I missed the point you make

Comment: Thanks gnat, glad you see my concern. And I know how to edit, thank you :)

Comment: @gnat Edited, if you see any chance of improvement, please comment. Removed opinionated first sentence as well.

Comment: This is a valid concern; we're discussing [potential ways](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/230882#comment758469_230882) to mitigate it. Unfortunately, there's no easy solution for "sub-topics" short of spinning off [a completely separate site](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/)... But that doesn't mean we can't make it easier for folks in niche areas to make their voices heard.

Comment: @Shog9 You could give top users more power. But there are also niche/niche with one top user. Tricky to get this to balance right. Don't get me wrong, I'm all for attacking the queue.

Comment: I see your point, but my question would be: why does your point apply here and not right now? The answer is that they are one and the same - now versus hypothetically allowing gold tag badge holders to close. Take a popular tag (c#) versus encryption. In c# 4.6% of all questions are currently closed. In encryption 6.4%; the majority of users closing encryption questions in that list? Not users who primarily answer encryption questions. Seeing as how most of these questions were not tagged with a popular tag, none of that would have been affected - and the rates are still pretty close to equal.

Comment: Let's take the highest voted closed encryption question as an example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-passwords **+175** . The users who closed it were 3 gold tag badge users in php and 2 silver php tag badge users. That was literally the first one I looked at in the list, and is the most prominent. How should that have changed if you propose these users do not understand the encryption aspect of this question?

Comment: @TravisJ Hmmyeah, closed as a dupe - not that hard. And the +175 questions are not the issue. Although I'm impressed with your statistics fu, you haven't *fully* turned my opinion I'm afraid. I don't see the reasoning behind the percentages of C# and Encryption. The main reason for questions to get closed is that somebody has chosen to close it it seems - maybe allowing the gold badge to close questions will only affect those that were already going to be closed. But if that's the case we don't need the solution. Hmm, thinking in circles, I'm off to bed :P

Comment: @TravisJ, if it is a question about encryption where the "php" is not important, then it should not have had the php tag in the first place.