# Let moderators disable the dupehammer for certain tags

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, moderator-tools, dupehammer

Recently [it was announced that the new "weighted" close votes from tag badge holders will be going network-wide.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16420780#16420780) I'd like to request that moderators have the ability to disable this for certain tags.

On the site that I am a mod on, [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com), the [code-golf] tag accounts for over 50% of questions on the site. (We've been talking about getting in more diversity, but that's another discussion.) Clearly, giving users the ability to unilaterally close half the questions on the site is probably not a good idea.

This could apply for other tags for which tag badges do not necessarily imply expertise - for example, a user having a tag badge in the [[beginner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner?sort=newest&pageSize=50)] tag on Code Review (sounds like a meta tag, but I'm not familiar with the site's policies and such) would not really imply that the user is an expert in... helping beginners?

When this new feature launches across the network, could it also come with some way to disable it on tags that wouldn't benefit from it?

Comment: This is probably a good idea, but it's kinda hard to duplicate code-golf questions, no?

Comment: How many users have a gold badge on PPCG? Do you mistrust them that much?

Comment: @Gilles [Apparently 1 person](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold).

Comment: @Gilles Good point, but assuming the site graduates (or at least gets more traffic) there will be more, and waiting until the situation gets out of hand is probably not the best idea.

Comment: +1 from me, but maybe it's time to get rid of `code-golf` - isn't it redundant, kind of like having `programming` on StackOverflow?

Comment: @slugster Code Golf [isn't the only thing we do.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/908/3808) We've got a whole slew of other "genres," and we plan to add non-challenges that are actually questions soon. But again, that's another discussion.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We originally thought this would be necessary too.

[Then we looked at the distribution of gold badges.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/230882#230882)

I think you can probably stand to moderate *one person* if he decides to go rogue on his own area of expertise. As soon as there are two people, you have a balance - one can revert the other's actions. Three people and you're back to moderating situations where there's a majority. And so on. If more than a few people take action on a single post, the system will automatically raise a flag asking you to check it out - so once there are more than a handful of closures possible in a day, you're gonna find out about any trouble.

If a particular tag is too broad, or doesn't reflect actual knowledge of a topic... Then there's a problem with the tagging on your site. **Fix it!**

Comment: To me, this is a self-correcting problem. If there are enough questions in a particular tag for one or more people to get gold badges, there are likely enough questions that most people won't be able to find the duplicates. But the people most invested in the tag will be. So rather than put them through the rigamarole of closing, flagging, and waiting, why not just let them be the experts they are?

Comment: Plus duplication is the gentlest of close reasons, it's not like the gold badge holders are being given the brass knuckles of off-topicness to one-hit K.O. questions with.

Comment: Only because the "Closed as **Too awesome for us**" reason got cut to save space.

Comment: umm... the code-golf tag works just fine. Can you suggest a replacement? Or PPCG exempt from the last paragraph?

Comment: I'm not the one complaining about the tag, @Jan. *If* [codegolf] failed to capture a reasonably specific area of expertise, then it might present a problem - otherwise, a gold badge in that tag should be just as meaningful as a gold badge anywhere else.

Comment: @shog9 Would you say the same about the `discussion` tag on meta sites, particularly since the meta sites *require* special tags so there are a lot of questions tagged `discussion`?

Comment: This might be broken on meta for... Well, all the usual meta reasons, @adam. We'll see.