# How would dupehammer react on posts with > 1 tags?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, moderator-abilities, binding-vote

> I raised this question in [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers?cb=1#comment19986_254590) on MSO, but I think it'd help
>   a wider audience as a separate question.

Let us say, there is a question tagged with more than one badge (for sake of assumption, take them to be [`mysql`, `php` and `sql`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+mysql+sql)). This question has a duplicate already but a user only has a gold tag badge for the `sql` tag (or `mysql` or `php`).

How would the [weighted close vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/212576) act in this scenario? Would the vote act as a normal close vote in this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Tim Post's response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/152515) to that feature request you linked:

> You can instantly close as a duplicate any question that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.

It sounds like if you have a gold tag badge for any of the tags, your close vote will be unilateral, like a mod's.

Which makes sense, because otherwise the feature would be useless. Think about what it'd mean if you had to have a gold badge for *every* tag on the question before your vote would be unilateral, and how often that'd mean someone could actually *use* this feature.