# What does gold badge icon near user marked question as duplicate mean

Tags: support, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

Recently [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660519/remove-check-box-blue-border) was marked by duplicate. Screenshot:

> [image]

I see an icon of gold badge near user marked question as duplicate (j08691).
And how did he marked it as duplicate alone, not being a moderator?

Comment: Oh cool, the badge is a nice addition. I like. But what's the bug?

Comment: Tag gold badge holders can unanimously close as duplicate questions that are tagged with any tag in which they have a gold badge.

Comment: Hovering over the circle brings up a tooltip that explains it, even down to which tag granted the user permission to unilaterally close.

Comment: @Troyen Ok. But I am on mobile now (and was).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a bug, but a feature recently introduced across all sites to allow users with gold badges in that tag to moderate duplicates in their tag with a single binding vote.

See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/165931

Several things I like about this feature:

1. Over use of tags increases the change an expert can handle low quality / duplicate questions with quick results.
2. Experts generally have a great sense of the domain and there are ways this is tracked and reviewable by others if needed (even if you don't consider flagging and comments).