# Hammer indication missing when closing as dupe through the API

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, api, dupehammer

As we all know by now, when a power user is using a binding close vote, [there is visual indication](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231622/what-does-gold-badge-icon-near-user-marked-question-as-duplicate-mean):

[image]

However, as can be seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158478/are-more-mini-sites-coming), when I closed a question as duplicate via the iOS app that indication is missing, even though it's the dupehammer binding vote:

[image]

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: Hmmm... The gold badge thingy is programmed on the client? *[rubs hands together fiendishly]*

Comment: @RobertHarvey nope, just tried with JS disabled and it's still there so it's server side. Whatever code setting the flag is running only when closing from the "ordinary" site, when doing it via the app (i.e. using API) the flag is not set. Also note that early usage of the hammer is not marked e.g. [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231544/how-to-start-chat-with-particular-user) where I voted as usual through the site itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug doesn't occur anymore; I just closed [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407844/4751173) as a duplicate via the iOS app (which uses the API), and the hammer indication is shown:

[image]