# The little icon for new gold badge super closing powers doesn't always appear

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

Here's a counter-example of the expected gold circle icon:

[image: icon missing]

Compare with:

[image: icon present]

I'm not certain of when the powers came into play, precisely, but since FredOverflow is neither a moderator nor the owner of that post, I can't see how else he would have marked it as a duplicate single-handedly except for this gold badge power.

Unless I'm missing something…

Comment: Maybe it was closed [through the app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231777/hammer-indication-missing-when-closing-as-dupe-through-the-app)

Comment: Perhaps it's just that the banners are cached somehow, and that old post pre-dates the introduction of the gold icon.

Comment: @mhlester: Mmmmm interesting.

Comment: I've pinged Fred to find out whether he uses the app. Only if he says he never does will I insist that this question not be dupe-closed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't have a smart phone, so no :)

Comment: @Haney: "the lack of an icon on a few posts is not going to hurt anybody." Really? I totally disagree. I fail to understand how a developer's OCD can let this pass! The gold icon is there _for a reason_, and leaving it to appear _only in some cases_ (as is the case here, inherently) is inconsistent, messy and confusing. Can't you just do a one-time batch update of all close banners?

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier I agree. I'll update it now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit let me check on the batch run, I can certainly see if it's viable!

Comment: @Haney: Thanks. It may be that there is too much risk of older banners elsewhere totally breaking through such an action. Still, if you could perhaps do it on just the ones affected by this bug, I really do think it'd be a net gain.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There was a short time after the feature launched that the gold badge icon did not appear. It was added about a day or two later and did not apply retroactively.

So this suggests that the rendering of the "closed by XXX" box is done at the time that the question is closed and cached indefinitely.

---

So any dupe-hammer closure that happened during that initial window of one or two days does not have the gold badge icon.

Comment: Worth to mention, that mobile view and apps also do not show the icon.

Comment: The entire box is not cached indefinitely. There is likely some sort of flag for the user that gets set if they close it while holding the tag badge. A moderator's diamond is not cached indefinitely and gets removed from everything when they're no longer a moderator, which would create a similar-appearing notice where it was closed by one user with no trace of how the user closed it by themselves.

Comment: @animuson Also, the user display name changes in the box if they change it in their profile... The way the usage of dupehammer is recorded can be seen in [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/228481/): e.g., `"BindingReason":{"GoldTagBadge":"c#"}`

Comment: Ah, so only part of the banner is cached - probably in obscure ways that can't be determined without looking at the their source code.

Comment: It's not that obscure. You can see in PostHistory table that the first question linked above has the closure event recorded with `"Voters":[{"Id":252000,"DisplayName":"FredOverflow"}]` while the second has it `"Voters":[{"Id":385378,"DisplayName":"NikiC","BindingReason":{"GoldTagBadge":"php"}}]` They just did not record the  BindingReason in the database for the first days of this feature.