# A better metric for close vote superpowers

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, dupehammer

Just to make my position clear, I'm opposed to the concept of any one person having powers to close questions, but am aware of [the circumstances that have led to this being implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/).

That said, I don't think that the right metric has been used to award the hammer.

I would be far more convinced that this is a good idea if wielders of this power were chosen on the basis of the *reliability* of their previous close votes.

Technical knowledge is not the same skill as judicial powers.

The ratio of *correct* close votes that a user has made (i.e. votes cast that actually contribute to the ultimate closure of a question) could easily be calculated. If the ratio is high enough over a minimum number of votes then they could be awarded the hammer.

Comment: Given that the capability only applies to closing as duplicate, it seems like technical knowledge is probably more relevant in that case.

Comment: @TimStone ...but technical knowledge is *implicit* with a high ratio of *correct* close votes, and it filters out those users who make snap judgements and get it wrong. Two birds, one stone...

Comment: Only if the close votes are for duplicate questions, but yes, that's true. I'm not sure there's really any significant reason for concern though, other than to say "doing it this way might technically be a bit more appropriate."