# Why a particular question is not closed immediately if one of the close voters have gold badge for a particular tag?

Tags: support, dupehammer

We all know about tag gold badge. If a user has a tag gold bage, he can close a question under particular tag immediately.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874269/command-line-tool-to-format-tables) is asked under particular tags `perl,bash,awk` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui) user have a tag gold badge for bash. He put the first close vote on that question but it fails to close immediately, Why?

Comment: Hammer worked fine for me. :) Seriously now, the answer in the dupe clearly says: *You can instantly close **as a duplicate** any question that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for*

Comment: so we can retag the questions and place the hammer on it.

Comment: @AvinashRaj no, abuse prevention was part of the design.  The dup-hammer only works for questions that had the tag originally.

Answer (score 3):

Because the Thor's Hammer gold badge users are given [only applies to duplicate close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/152515). They don't have the ability to unanimously close for other reasons - that was an off topic close vote.

It might expand to those reasons in the future, but it's only duplicates for now as a trial.