# Rationale behind voting to close "Duplicate of.." causing the question to be closed instantly?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

On occasion I noticed that voting to close "duplicate of" instantly closes the question and marks it as a duplicate.

I've seen it happening for identical questions (reposts) and that makes sense. It also happened with this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584646/common-practise-for-spritekit-games-with-timers).

I'm just wondering how does SO (currently) determine that the question to be closed should rather be closed instantly instead of simply recording my vote?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders

Comment: thanks, I expected this was somewhere on here but couldn't find it :)