# Why wasn't my close vote binding?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, vote-to-close, dupehammer

On SO, I have binding close vote on the c# tag. There was [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25590624/when-does-custom-attribute-constructor-executes) that was an obvious duplicate of a previous question I was involved in, so I voted to close.

The question, though having the c# tag, wasn't closed, but it just received one close vote (mine).

I wonder why this happened. Is this because the instant-close-vote only counts on the original tags only (the c# tag was edited in later, before casting my vote) or is it a bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `c#` tag was added in an edit.

Only the tags in the *first revision* count when dupe hammering; this is by design, to prevent users editing in a tag they have a gold badge for.

Quoting from [Tim Post's announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212):

> If a question has a tag where you have a gold badge, and **it was part of the original set of tags applied to the question**, you can mark it as a duplicate with a single vote.

Emphasis mine.

Shog [explains why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230882/140890):

> Second, this power should be based on the tags in the *first* revision of the question. I know, that cuts out a lot of potentially-useful effects when it comes to niche tags - but it also cuts out a ton of potential for abuse, without also making it a major headache to figure out what a given vote is actually worth. For the tags where this actually *matters*, it matters because they happen to also be the most obvious tags for a whole bunch of questions - *if* you want an answer, that is.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Any reference for that?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: this was part of the original design, looking it up.

Comment: Got it. Just missing it when reading the post.

Answer (score 12):

I designed the feature around the abuse case of someone finding a question they don't particularly care for, throwing a tag on it where they have a gold badge, and marking it as a duplicate. It was the simplest path to implementation, and folks on our side were a bit nervous about how it would be used, even with those safeguards in place. That's why it has to be part of the original set of tags, and I made it that way fully realizing that new users are quite often not the best taggers.

It was designed to give folks that have obviously deep knowledge of a particular tag *and the content we have in the tag* a very low-friction way of keeping duplicates managed, and it's working exactly as intended.

For the most part, I'm *quite* pleased with the restraint that folks have shown with this privilege, to the point that I'm now looking at what we might be able to put into people's hands at the silver badge level. I'm not saying that we'll relax the safe guards around it *soon*, but if it continues to be used as responsibly as it has been, that could be on the table.

Comment: Thanks. The problem in this case that the single original tag has no gold badge holders and it obviously missed the major tag on it. Thanks for elaborating.

Comment: What about allowing the hammer if a tag was added by a moderator i.e. consider tags added by moderators as if they were part of the original revision?

Comment: Or when added by anyone except for the voter?

Comment: I am more than fine with the restriction; it is rare enough for a post not to have a tag I can hammer with; the exceptions are easily handled with a little patience and / or chat room coordination.

Comment: @Arjan I considered looking at tags added by anyone _other_ than the one using the metaphorical 'hammer', but that's insanely easy to coordinate in chat. With a lot of tags already coordinating janitorial stuff using chat (and they do a *fantastic job*), that didn't seem like a great option. This was controversial enough that with more than a trivial amount of actual abuse cases, it would have been reverted. I opted to see with what folks did with it, and so far, I think we're coming to a place where it can be less restricted. For the sake of diligence alone, though, a bit more time is needed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's a little wonky, because mods can single-vote everything _already_, and I don't think cases where the mod simply noticed something incorrectly tagged and then fixed it, now open to be closed by a gold badge user, are abundant enough to be meaningful.

Comment: I understand the logic here, but perhaps it is worth considering tags added in subsequent edits by *different* editors. That still solves the abuse problem, unless there's sockpuppetry going on, but that's not a problem unique to close voting.

Comment: @Cody I can already see the "plz-add-tag" requests in the chat rooms, followed almost blindly.

Comment: Ugh, I try really hard to forget about chat rooms.

Comment: @Cody I had a glimpse once, it's full with "plz-close", "plz-downvote" and "plz-delete". I doubt many users really bother to check, they just follow the herd. Not judging or anything, usually it's really crap they help close/downvote/remove but still... giving them hammers (they currently don't have) won't be a good idea.

Comment: @TimPost fair enough, suggestion retracted. ;)

Comment: The overall idea of tag-badge–related privileges is a really good one, because it ties domain-specific knowledge to some privilege in a way that mere reputation never can. I just wish I could think of any low-hanging fruit to nominate for this sort of treatment. The only downside I can see is that it doesn’t work well with smaller sites or with less popular tags, but arguably the smaller sites don’t tax their respective mod teams so much, and so this is less an issue there. Or maybe if you do add silver, it might still have some additional reputation requirement, or just be for some sites.

Comment: @tchrist It also fails on sites where new *major* tags are constantly being created, such as Ask Ubuntu, where every new release of the OS *is* a major tag. I've been chewing on that for a while now, without much progress unfortunately. I keep coming back to 'tag relation' which isn't at all .. minor, as far as features go, at least not in the sense of giving folks a super vote.