# Increase close and reopen vote weight for bronze and silver tag badge holders

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

Yesterday I finally reached 3k and able to cast close and reopen votes (yay!).
A week ago I [earned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/79/discussion?userid=259214) bronze discussion tag badge and today thought: maybe increase close and reopen votes weight for bronze and silver tag badge holders? These users *also* have earned some trust in these tags, just not as much as gold badge holders. Also it will help moderation. I propose:

- 2 votes weight for bronze tag badge holders
- 3 votes weight for silver tag badge holders

Comment: What about gold?

Comment: @Uni for gold it [was already increased](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders).

Comment: only for duplicates...

Comment: With the exception of the golden hammer for duplicates (where a gold badge holder in the tag can close a duplicate question) and moderators, no one has a "vote weight" for anything; all votes count as one. IOW, even a gold badge user has no extra close or reopen "vote weight", and I certainly don't agree that a 3K user (regardless of bronze or silver badges in a tag) are familiar or knowledgeable enough to merit more close/reopen power ("weight") than anyone else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I personally don't at all like the idea of "close vote weight" because it just makes the system too complicated and confuses users as to why the question was closed by fewer users than normal. If it's not a binding vote, then it should be a regular close vote.

Also, as you have demonstrated, it's quite easy to get a bronze tag badge before you even gain the privilege of voting to close questions. We don't want users who have never even participated in actual close votes before having increased weight in certain tags. It only takes 100 votes for a bronze tag badge, which means it can be achieved with as little as 1,000 reputation. A gold tag badge requires 1,000 votes in a single tag, which in a simple world implies the user has gained at least 10,000 reputation on the site overall. At that point the user has much more experience with the site and can be safely trusted with increased weight on their close votes (even if it only applies to duplicates at the moment).

Comment: Agreed, have nothing to say. I, however, do not know any user that earned a bronze tag badge having 1000 repz.