# Which users appear on "on hold"/"closed" messages and why?

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close, on-hold, binding-vote

It was my understanding that 5 votes were required to put a question on hold or to close it. However, when users who voted to put a question on hold are listed there are often not 5. [This question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34328/do-these-dreams-i-am-having-about-the-end-of-the-world-have-meaning) for instance only appears to have one user, [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6475/how-literally-do-you-take-and-universally-apply-what-jesus-said) lists two users and [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34288/what-is-the-difference-between-evangelizing-and-proselytizing) lists five. Which users will appear on an on hold/closed message and why? Is it always the case that five users are required?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See that diamond just after the name of the user?

It means that user is a moderator on the site.

Moderators have binding votes - they can decide all by themselves.

See [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role)

Additionally, people with a gold tag badge in one of the original tags on a question can close it as a duplicate, without the need of other people to close, as discussed in [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212).