# Is there anything to stop a Gold Tag person editing a tag in to close any question they want?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

Someone with a gold badge in a tag can Dupe Hammer, and close it in one go, like a moderator.

Is there anything to stop a Gold Tag user from editing in that tag to close it? Or is that allowed, like edit to unvote?

Comment: @roombatron um no, it may answer indirectly but it defo isn't a duplicate... Totally different questions, and this should be separated - it took a while for people to find it for a start.

Comment: "You can instantly close as a duplicate any question that was **originally asked** with a tag you have a gold badge for" - see the part in bold. That's  not indirectly, that's directly answers your question here.

Comment: When the answer to question A is given in question B, it makes question A be duplicate of question B. That's one of the many quirks of Meta.

Comment: Okay then that's fine :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Though [current tags are taken into account](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/268281/152859) when checking if the person can close a question using dupe hammer, it also check if that person was the one to insert the relevant tag, and in such case it won't let them use the hammer.

So, they wouldn't be able to do this.

Comment: Ahh so there is a mechanism. Good, thanks :)

Comment: I know I've seen this described in a FAQ or Help Center article or some other meta post somewhere before, but I'll be damned if I can find it now.

Comment: @JasonC found it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/158100)

Comment: @rene A ha! That's where it was. Good sleuthing.