# Dupe hammer - "original tags only" limitation

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

The question was asked and answered earlier: [Is there anything to stop a Gold Tag person editing a tag to close any question they want?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251851/212464) and the answer is "yes - only original tags on a question count for the dupe hammer".

I have a problem with that. A question [such as this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/304109/26969) is absolutely about Newtonian Mechanics - but OP only tagged it "rigid body dynamics". Had it been correctly tagged, I could have hammered it. As it is, I cannot - and the question lingers unnecessarily.

What does the community think - should the dupe hammer holder be permitted to edit in the tag, then close the question? It has a small potential for abuse - but a big potential for helping clean up the sites.

My preferred solution is not the one currently implemented. Would love to hear others' thoughts.

Comment: I think that if it's edited by someone else it can be dupe hammered as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - do you have a reference for that? Because the links in the answer above say "original tags" quite explicitly. But it's over two years old. For sure, when I tried tagging the question it didn't close...

Comment: Well the answer is not official, I'll try to test it soon and update here.

Comment: Find someone else to apply the correct tags, and then dupehammee it. That should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to worry. The answer you found is wrong/misleading/outdated.

As proved in [those revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/289554/revisions), if other user is retagging the question and adds a tag you have gold tag badge for, you will be able to dupe hammer it. (the linked question was originally posted only with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag for which I don't have gold badge, then someone changed it to [support](/questions/tagged/support) where I do have).

Comment: "Outdated" is the right option. [Originally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212) only the original tags mattered. Then that was [updated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268281) to use updated tags.

Comment: Thanks @zaq, I tried to edit the outdated answer, though it looks bit weird now.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This is clearly better than the original state described in the linked answer, although it leaves unanswered my original discussion question: "should the behavior be changed?" so I can tag and close? I think the possibility of abuse is small.

Comment: @Floris no no, that would be too tempting. Will edit my answer soon.

Comment: Incidentally I have left a comment under the original question (for which the one where you edited the answer was a dupe) to get that updated...