# How can a question be marked duplicate by two users?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, duplicate-answers

I marked an answer as duplicate. How is it possible that another user also marked that answer as duplicate? Shouldn't the question be closed on first marking of duplicate?

Let me explain

I marked an answer ([Enums: Retrieve enum value from enumeration name string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409546/enums-retrieve-enum-value-from-enumeration-name-string)) as duplicate of ([How should I convert a string to an enum in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c)). After doing that the former question is showing

[image]

How is possible that two users mark same question as duplicate? Shouldn't the question be closed on first marking of duplicate?

The other user has 4k reputation (as of today) and I guess minimum 3k is required to mark and answer as duplicate.

Am I correct or not?

Comment: Hover the yellow circle to see the answer.

Answer (score 6):

It's because Ric *voted* to close the question as dupe. Therefore, his name is included.

Normally you need 5 votes to close a question, and their names will be displayed. But since you are wielding the [dupe-hammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/241919), the question was closed when you voted to close as dupe.

> You can instantly close as a duplicate any question that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.

You have gold badge on [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), and the question was tagged with that tag.