# Can't single-handedly reopen a dupehammered Q after editing gold tag to another gold tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen, dupehammer

I dupehammered [Right way to add cronjob-threading functionality to Tomcat webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583772/right-way-to-add-cronjob-threading-functionality-to-tomcat-webapp) with gold [jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf) badge. Then OP complained and edited the question into a too broad recommendation request. While still a bad question, it technically isn't a dupe anymore. So I wanted to remove the dupe vote so it could be reclosed as offtopic / too broad. It's after all also not a JSF question, so I replaced the [jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf) by [java](/questions/tagged/java) first and then voted to reopen. However, in spite of that I also have a gold [java](/questions/tagged/java) badge, I got a message in a blue popup balloon with two or three sentences which boils down to something like below (sorry, missed the opportunity to make a screenshot and I can't find the exact message anywhere here):

> Sorry, we can't single-handedly reopen it as you participated in removing the [jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf) tag.

How does that make sense? Must I in the future remember to reopen before editing tags?

Comment: I know it's not a bug - definitely status-bydesign because the same person can't close and reopen the same question.

Comment: @angussidney: I've done it several times before (when I didn't change tags), hence this Q.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: I'm sure. *That* part does in turn make sense, but it would show up during close only, not during reopen. As of now, it doesn't show during close btw.

Comment: The disallowing of editing one of your gold tags in so that you can close the question has been baked into the hammer from the start, @IlmariKaronen: only the _initial_ version of the post counts for this purpose. This does appear to be a different problem.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Ah, good point. Please ignore my (now deleted) comment.

Comment: @JoshCaswell [This has changed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268278/it-looks-like-the-duplicate-banner-changed-how-does-it-work-now/268281#268281), now the dupehammer is based on current tags, but if you've edited the tags, your close vote is an ordinary vote. Which is a bit silly if you've edited the tags only to, say, remove one where you had a gold badge and add another one where you also had a gold badge. (It works symmetrically for closure and reopening, by the way.)

Comment: Ah, good to know, @Gilles, thanks.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, Gilles just made me aware that the behavior has changed; I don't remember anymore what your comment said, but it might be relevant again.

Comment: [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kUoab.png)

Comment: @Shadow: Thank you for the screenshot! I only remember a slight different message (or they changed it in the meanwhile without notifying here), but yes, it boils down to that message.

Comment: Yeah, it kept changing for a while. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 7):

This is one of those situations where I'm not sure the system can be smarter than the user.

The rules are:

1. There has to be a tag on the post *currently* in which you have a gold badge
2. You can't have been the first person to add that tag to the post (or have participated in adding it the first time)

Well, [jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf) wasn't on there anymore, and you did add the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag. So the system blocked you. As you noted, the only alternative would've been to reopen *first* and then edit.

A clever system might notice that you'd previously hammered the post closed and dug further to see if you'd removed the relevant tag yourself (or even just *always allow single-handed reopening* in cases where you'd previously single-handedly-closed); feel free to propose something like that as a feature, but I think we could only special-case this for reopening - there's too much potential for error and shenanigans if we try to divine intent for tag edits in the general case.

Comment: And if you start thinking about corner cases first, before implementing rules, here’s some food for thought: what if a gold badge holder single-handedly closes a question, but loses the gold badge after that and now wants to revert the closing. Should they be allowed to do that in this special case?