# Can I close, re-open, and close again with the dupehammer on two different tags?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

Related: [Can't single-handedly reopen a dupehammered Q after editing gold tag to another gold tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269103/cant-single-handedly-reopen-a-dupehammered-q-after-editing-gold-tag-to-another?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Say there's a question with two tags on which I have the gold badge. I dupehammered it once (with the notice showing one of the two tags), OP edited it somewhat, making another question a better fit (but sill a dupe). I can reopen unilaterally, but can I close it again unilaterally based on the other gold tag badge?

Note that I didn't edit any of the tags; both tags were present from the start.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. The number of tags you have dupehammer for is irrelevant. It's just any tag will let you use the dupehammer. You are still limited to one successful close vote on a question in the lifetime of that question. You can never cast another close vote on the question, regardless of whether you have dupehammer privileges or not.