Gold tag badge didn't allow single-vote duplicate question closure
As a gold badge holder for [the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim] tag on Arqade, I encountered an unexpected issue while reviewing a question in the Close Votes review queue. Despite the gold tag badge privilege being described as "can single-handedly mark [the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim] questions as duplicates," my close vote did not immediately close the question as a duplicate. At the time of writing, the question remains open.

This functionality has worked as expected in my past experiences. However, in this recent instance, it failed to operate correctly. Given this discrepancy between the stated privilege and the observed behavior, I suspect this might be a bug.

You added the tag yourself. That exempts you from using your hammer.

See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310784

You should have gotten a notification to this effect when you cast a close vote - it says something like "normally, you'd unilaterally close it but since it was you who added , the unilateral closure is omitted". Shows up on the top of the screen (or maybe top of the page?) if you cast a close vote. Although, I'm not sure if it does that in review queues.

@VLAZ Interesting, I didn't catch that message. I must have missed the notification, or maybe it doesn't appear in the review queue. It'd be more helpful if this detail was included in the privilege description instead of being tucked away in a meta post. That way, users would have a clearer understanding of how it functions.

This was because you added the tag yourself.
This system probably exists to prevent abuse, because otherwise anybody with 1 gold tag badge could hammer any question just by adding a tag to it.

Eh, well, it's pretty trivial how to overcome this. Leaving this as homework to figure out how. (Hint: order.)

@ShadowWizard The feature to allow changing the duplicate targets doesn't have this check at all, so effectively once anyone has a single gold tag badge one can change duplicate targets on any question.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog maybe that should be fixed...
