# Golden tag badge owner can insta-close questions not originally tagged with a tag they own a golden badge for

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, tag-badges

As explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/302251) (emphasys mine):

> - You can instantly close *as a duplicate* any question that was **originally asked** with a tag you have a gold badge for.

But golden tag badge owner can insta-close questions not originally tagged with a tag they own a golden badge for, as long as the question is tagged with one at the time they vote to close: [How do I write an output of one command into a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/731222/how-do-i-write-an-output-of-one-command-into-a-file).

- [Revision #1](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/731222/1): question is tagged with [files](/questions/tagged/files), [text](/questions/tagged/text) and [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) by OP; **The question is *not* tagged with** [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line);
- [Revision #2](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/731222/1): tags are not edited;
- [Revision #3](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/731222/1): [files](/questions/tagged/files), [text](/questions/tagged/text) and [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) are removed; [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line), [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [text-processing](/questions/tagged/text-processing) are added by muru;
- [Post is insta-closed](https://askubuntu.com/posts/731222/revisions) by heemayl, gold [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line) badge owner, as a duplicate of [How do I save terminal output to a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file). **But the tag was added by muru during revision #3**.

muru is also a gold [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line) badge owner, but it's not clear whether muru voted before or after having edited the post: so it might be either that the check is not done at all or that the only thing checked is whether the user closing the question is not the same user that added the tag.

Comment: I believe it’s just an error (or outdated information) in the post explaining the behaviour. As far as I know, a gold-badge user is prevented from using the dupehammer when they added the special tag themselves, but not when a different user added it. – Edit: Just found the duplicate; it is indeed as I wrote before. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268281

Comment: @editor, sorry but I rejected the edit. "dupehammer" is just as "meh" and jargonish as "insta-close" (also there were two other instances of "insta-close[d]" in the post).

Comment: @chirlu Indeed, thanks. Someone should edit that post.