# Mouseover Tooltip on Title; weird spacing

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, tooltips

When **mousing over** a link to a question on the main page, a tooltip appears with the first few sentences of the question.

When a question includes a picture or quote in those first sentences, this leads to weird spacing in the tool tip. It doesn't matter where specifically the picture or quote is in the first few sentences, of course. **Update**: Further testing shows this weirdness also happens with Lists (bulleted at least) and Video Embeds (On Movies.SE)

For comparison, how a normal paragraph break is shown:

> [image]
>   Single line break.

Picture as first paragraph in question:

> [image]
>   Notice the double blank line.

Quote, as second paragraph:

> [image]
>   Notice the triple line before and after the quoted text.

List as first paragraph:

> [image]
>   Single unneeded line break.

Youtube/Flash Embed as first paragraph on Movies.SE"

> [image]
>   This actually two issues, as for some reason embedding a video leads to the system rendering the question as having a `<p>` followed by the video `<div>` followed by another `<p>`.

I thought it may have had to do with how paragraph html marks are parsed, but the block quotes do not use `<p>` or `</p>`. Instead they use `<blockquote>`

The same issue happens if the picture is 1st, 2nd or 3rd paragraph, if the text of the question is short enough for those to be included.

Can this be fixed? It's on multiple stacks (First example is EE.SE, second is here on Meta.SE)

### Update: I looked at the source for the page, and the rendered title tag for the second example ([Golden tag badge owner can insta-close questions not originally tagged with a tag they own a golden badge for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274319/)) is

```
<h3><a href="/questions/274319/golden-tag-badge-owner-can-insta-close-questions-not-originally-tagged-with-a-ta" class="question-hyperlink" title="As explained here (emphasys mine):



  You can instantly close as a duplicate any question that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.



But golden tag badge owner can ...">Golden tag badge owner can insta-close questions not originally tagged with a tag they own a golden badge for [duplicate]</a></h3>
```

***Four line breaks (New Line characters) just dumped in.*** The fix would be easy. Eliminate multiple New Lines in a row when rendering the Title attribute. A better fix, include spaces in that. That question actually has 3 new lines, space, 1 new line, and then new line, 2 spaces, 3 new lines. Should be simple to implement, I'd think.

Comment: The tooltip rendering is not something that can be controlled by us - it is something the browser does (we put text/html in the title attribute - the browser takes it from there). Which one are you using and on which OS?

Comment: @Oded Safari 9.0.3 on OSX 10.10.5, but the tool tip is reflecting how the question is parsed by the site. The title attribute is being populated somehow, and that somehow isn't taking paragraph breaks or quotes, youtube embeds, or  lists into account, leading to awkward spacing.

Comment: @Oded I found the issue and the solution. See my update.

Comment: *Should be simple to implement, I'd think.* You're hired ... don't dare to increase page render time... good luck... ;)

Comment: @rene it already parses for markup like bolding to remove, adding a quick parse for multiple newlines would be a small change to existing infrastructure.

Comment: I do not know how the data is populated and the programming language used, but I think the solution would be replace, something like: `data.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine, System.Environment.NewLine);` (example in C#) :/

Answer (score 1):

As of the most recent build, we're trimming the repeated new lines mid-text to something more reasonable.

Comment: They currently seem to be super-trimmed -- I haven't seen mouse-over tooltips on question titles in about a week.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Please submit a new bug report.

Comment: Gah, sorry -- meant to include the link and somehow didn't: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291982/162102  Sigh; Mondays are the worst...

Comment: @MonicaCellio Haha cool. I'll ping this week's bug duty winner to take a look.