# All votes to close a question (not an answer) should be accompanied by a helpful comment or resource

Tags: feature-request, comments, review, vote-to-close

I'm getting tired and irritated of people going to a question and voting to close without bothering to add clarification.

For example, I ask a question and then someone votes to close because it's unclear, fair enough. To me, I have asked exactly what I'm asking, It's clear as day, It's literally the last line in the OP. To simply vote to close like that gives the impression that the person that voted didn't bother to read the entire question.

How exactly is the OP supposed to improve their question so it can be answered  if you just vote to close and then wander off?

Why should the person that voted to close just be able to vote to close without leaving something helpful to improve the question?

I understand that sometimes it's obvious as why the question should be closed and that you don't have the time to to give a reason for every question; but I'd like to point out that even if poorly written the writer took the time to ask the question, the least you can do is give a reason or link to specific thing that would improve the question so that they can get a useful response.

Help them so they can help themselves and so on, aren't we about improvements? How exactly can we be about that if we don't help people to do that or point people in the right direction or give them the correct tools to do that.

So I propose, You can't vote to close a question without leaving some form of critique or a useful link that would improve the question.

Comment: We are getting tired an irritated by this suggestion. It has been asked 1000s or times :/

Comment: @DavidPostill I doubt this has been asked that often.  Suggesting downvotes need to comment has been suggested many thousands of times, but commenting when closing I doubt has even been brought up 100 times.

Comment: @Servy OK, so I exaggerated :)

Comment: Any comment I am forced to make will simply be "NT" most people dont want to know what I think of a question or answer I down vote.  You as the author can edit a question once it's closed, if you do that, it's put into a queue to be opened again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there is a consensus the question should be closed, there is a helpful comment stating what is wrong. The close reason does do that. If there is just one user voting to close and no one agrees, I don't see why he or she should be forced to leave a comment. What additional value does the comment bring? Nothing.

The only thing it can do is prevent the question from being closed within the short amount of time the voting to close happens (mostly in my most-used sites). Still, forcing to comment is not the way to solve that.

If a question gets improved, the community can reopen it, just the same way as it was closed. There is even a review queue to bring attention to questions that can be reopened.

Comment: But once the question is closed, can the OP re-open the question with improvements?

Comment: The OP can't reopen. The community can. Depending on the close type, one single vote can be enough.

Comment: @Thermatix the OP can edit, then the question reach a Reopen Review queue, or with enough reputation (I think 300) can also cast the first reopen vote, also sending it to the same queue.

Comment: Technically, OP with a gold tag badge could reopen their dupe-marked question ;)

Comment: Indeed, they can. Not always appreciated by the community :) @nicael

Answer (score 3):

One close vote <s>does not a summer make</s> will not close a question (except for the so-called ['dupehammer'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212), or a ♦ moderator). Only when the community reaches a certain consensus, it will be put on hold, with a banner indicating possible ways to improve the question.

Afterwards, when somebody (the OP or somebody else) edits the question, e.g. to make it more clear after being put on hold as unclear, it will end up in the Reopen Votes review queue, where other community members will take a look at it and see if the question has been improved enough to reopen it.

Comment: "One close vote does will not close a question" > It does in some cases. Voting as duplicate with the gold tag badge for example.

Comment: I see, I wasn't aware that there was a re-open queue, I thought it was closed and that was it.

Comment: And that's a problem, becuase sometimes the question only seems on the surface to be a duplicate when the OP is asking somthing else, Like this one, I did see that question but it's not exactly the same question.

Comment: @PatrickHofman thanks, I added this to the answer

Comment: The same user can insta-reopen it @Thermatix

Comment: A moderator super-vote can also place a question instantly On Hold and likewise Re-opened.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Same user?

Comment: Yes, if voted to close as duplicate by a gold tag badge holder.

Comment: If the question was closed by a single user (be it moderator or gold dupe-hammer) you can even ping that user via a comment reply. /cc @Thermatix

Comment: @PatrickHofman sorry, should have been clearer, I meant what do you mean by same user? Which user?

Comment: @Thermatix the user with gold badge who closed a question with a single vote. (See Patrick's first comment: "Voting as duplicate with the gold tag badge for example")

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification, I was thinking that but wasn't sure, it was a little vague.

Comment: Yeah it was, sorry for that @Thermatix