# If a golden tag badge owner votes for a question to migrate away, will it be migrated on the spot?

Tags: support, migration, tag-badges

Thus, also the vote to migrate decisions of the golden tag badge owners are binding?

Comment: The limits of the dupehammer for gold tag badges seem to be documented at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders

Comment: @PolyGeo Ok, thx!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope.

Only binding for duplicates.