# Rule for master duplicates to have a 80% positive score

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-answers, duplicate-suggestions

Selecting confusing questions with negative score as "master duplicates" just adds more confusion and despair than help.

Take this one as an example:

[const { makeBadgeData: getBadgeData } = require('../../lib/badge-data')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532235/const-makebadgedata-getbadgedata-require-lib-badge-data)

The linked question is highly controversial.

[image: controversial]

I think that's an indicator of the [curse of knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_knowledge) and disparity between level of people who already know about a topic and those who are puzzled .

Because [curse of knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_knowledge) is one of unconscious biases ("those students are too dumb to learn calculus") it can be circumvented with a rule that only questions that are clear or interesting enough can be selected as "master duplicate". Technically only questions above certain positive threshold can be selected.

Originally I suggested 10 positive votes, but relative measure 80% positive should be appropriate for highly specific topics.

Note that I am not speaking about answers here. If the question is not the same as mine, or if I don't understand it, I will unlikely to be satisfied 
with reading the answer even if it eventually solves my problem.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but on Meta, downvotes on feature requests mean that people disagree with the request.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I see. How to provide counter-arguments then? Comments?

Comment: Edit your question to add more explanation. This also unlocks the voting, so if someone changes their mind about your proposal, they can change their vote.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. What if it's a naive question? Assuming it's never goes HNQ, it will never receive a huge number of votes, so it'll never reach 10 (particularly on the sites which are smaller than SO). But it'll get asked again and again. Remember that a score of 10 is quite rare on most sites.

Comment: @Chair yup, I thought about this too and removed 10 upvotes with 80% positive. See the edit.

Comment: It doesn't matter how good the question is, it matters how good the answer to the question is. I'd close a question as a dupe of a -1000 question if that question had a +10k answer that was a perfect solution to the problem. I've got a FR on meta.so for closing as dupe of an *answer*, which would prevent question quality or clarity from ever being a problem in the first place. [Check it out.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366716/vote-to-close-as-a-duplicate-of-an-answer)

Answer (score 11):

I see many problems with this:

- Sometimes, a user asks the same poor question twice. It's appropriate to close the second question as a duplicate of the first one, even if it has a negative score.
- A great many well-worded and useful questions never get to a score of 10, because they were asked in a niche technology, on a small site with little voting or because they haven't been around for long enough. It's good to encourage more voting as you proposed, but the number of questions is simply too big for it to work.

  - 80/20 is probably a better rule, but a +1/-0 question already qualifies. Did you really mean to do that?
- What [PolyGeo says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319097/295232): a mediocre question can still be useful because it receives a good ansswer.

If you have a problem with a handful of poorly chosen *originals*, see if you can find somebody with a gold tag badge in that particular tag (e.g. in chat) who is willing to use his [dupehammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/295232) to reopen them, and maybe find a better original for the duplicate questions. If the problem persists, and new poor originals keep being chosen, you can raise a question on the site's own Meta (e.g. [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)) and hope people read it and take heed.

Comment: `+1/-0` is fine, yes. It has not yet collected enough data to be considered a bad choice, but the entrypoint that scored `+5/-6` is definitely not good.

Comment: **originals** and `dupehammer`. Well, I learned something new today. =) That will surely work for me in the future, but I am afraid not everybody is as persistent.

Answer (score 8):

If a poor question is asked that receives negligible/negative votes, but receives a useful answer, and then the same question is asked again, I think it highly appropriate for the second question to be closed as a duplicate of the first.

Consequently, your proposal that a score of less than 10 (or less than "80% positive") should prevent a question from becoming a master duplicate would not work well in this and, I suspect, many other cases.

I think a much simpler solution to your issue is to edit the poor first question to improve it.

Comment: And what if the question is not the same or have a better quality?

Comment: @anatolytechtonik That sounds like two different specific scenarios rather than the generic proposal that you made in your question.

Comment: Reworded the proposal with more detail. See the new edit.

Comment: Poor questions are poor, because the frame or mindset they were written in is hard to digest. Editing that question without changing the frame is hard. Changing the frame often means replacing the question.

Comment: @anatolytechtonik any question where "the frame or mindset they were written in is hard to digest" is crying out to be edited to make what it is asking clearer,