# Can a question be immediately closed without any close votes?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, closed-questions

One of my recent question was closed immediately (within 1 min) without any votes to close. I wonder if this is normal if the question is *not* blatantly off-topic, spam, etc.

We should assume that questions were mostly asked out of goodwill.

Comment: Do you mean that your question was closed without any up or down votes, or do you mean that you question was closed without any *votes to close*?

Comment: @RobertColumbia Without vote to close

Comment: Do you mean [this one](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/posts/53267/timeline)? It was closed by a moderator. If not which one? Add a link in your question.

Comment: @RobertLongson There are more than one instance of this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It wasn't closed without votes, but it may be that the close vote was *binding*, because it was [closed by a ♦ moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators), or [closed as a duplicate by a gold tag badge holder](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/295232).

Meta Stack Exchange gets a lot of blatantly off-topic questions, and the moderators here use one of my scripts that closes and even deletes them, without casting a downvote. So the absence of downvotes (if that's what you're wondering) also doesn't say anything.

Answer (score 4):

As Glorfindel answered the first question succinctly, I'd like to answer the second implied question: "Is this normal?"

#### Yes, this is normal

Some questions are just blatantly off-topic, duplicates of a "canonical question" or otherwise impossible to answer.

In such a situation, a moderator can simply decide to close a question instead of waiting for the community to get together enough votes to close the question through vote.

---

#### An Example

One kind of question that pops up time and time again on [InfoSec](https://security.stackexchange.com/) is some form of "Can you crack this hash for me?" to which the answer is always "No, we are not a hash cracking service."

When encountering such a question, a moderator will close the question immediately and explain why.

---

#### Should it be this way?

I would wager, yes. When asking a question, you want feedback as quickly as possible. If your question is missing a critical piece of information, then you want that feedback as quickly as possible, so you can edit your questin and get it into good shape.

And if a question is completely unsalvagable, i.e. blatantly off-topic, spam, etc... then closing it quickly  makes sense too.

---

#### What if a user disagrees with a mod decision?

I personally never encountered a situation in which a moderator closed a question shortly after it was submitted, while I thought it was a perfectly fine question.

But it's very much possible that such a situation could occur. In this case, I would **vote to re-open** the question, as well as leave a comment behind as to why specifically I believe the question is fine as-is.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have a couple of questions that were clearly not off-topic or spam: I even spent a lot of time explaining the question.  But they were immediately closed without any community close vote.

Comment: @HighGPA In this case, it's likely the questions fall outside the scope of the site for one reason or another. I would ask on the meta-site of that specific site as to why these questions are not suitable, and how they can be improved.